# Is [absent-players] a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

While answering another question here in meta, I noticed we actually have a [absent-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absent-players) tag. It had few questions tagged as it, though (and one tagged as [missing-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/missing-players), which should be a synonym imo, but I don't have score in any of them to suggest it). It draws attention that we have a good number of "What to do when a player can't come to a session" but most of them are not tagged with the [absent-players](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/absent-players) tag. Is this because the tag is redundant or not useful at all or what?

Answer (score 12):

## Yes, the tag is useful.

First, it describes the problem very well. It's clear what we are looking at when we see this tag - we are looking at a problem about one or more players missing one or more sessions, and probably what to do due to this absence. This is as descriptive as, for example, [powergaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powergaming), IMO.

Even contrary to [powergaming](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powergaming), I don't think this tag is a specific subset of the [problem-players] tag. I went on and edited some questions adding the tag that I think are representative to my point here: the problems are closely (or exclusively) related to a player missing. [How can I quickly adjust encounters for variable party sizes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/124568/43856), [How do you deal with missing players?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1273/43856), [How to deal with a player missing the first session of a campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28019/43856). Note that, as with [How to deal with a player missing the first session of a campaign](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/28019/43856), for example, there isn't a problem-players problem, people just can't show up every session, it happens, and it's useful for us to know how to (better) handle it.

**TL;DR:** *Yes, I think the tag is useful. I don't think we should be rallying to edit the tag into old questions, but if we come across one that is about players missing sessions, the consequences to it and how to handle it, we should add the tag to the question.*

Comment: Agreed. There seem to be quite a few tags that are useful but simply don't get used that often, presumably because people don't know they exist. The solution is simply to tag questions appropriately if you notice them missing a relevant tag.

Comment: @V2Blast Yeap, I was just worried that they don't get used because people actually think it's not a good tag at all. Reason I created this meta question before actually start editing further than the ones I have already done.